# JQUERY & AJAX "Internal Server Error"

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

Have a script as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#Vessel_ID").change(function () {

        var vesselID = parseInt($("#Vessel_ID").val());

        if (!isNaN(vesselID)) {
            var voyageID = $("#Voyage_ID");
           voyageID.empty(); // this line is for clear all items from Voyage dropdown
          voyageID.append($("<option></option").val("").html("Select voya"));

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetVoyages","VM")',
                type: "GET",
                data: { vesselID: vesselID },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (i, val) {
                        voyageID.append($("<option></option>").val(val.VoyageID.html(val.Voyage_ID)))
                    })     

                        }
                    ,
                    error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
  alert(xhr.statusText);
  alert(textStatus);
  alert(error);


                    }
                });

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

INDEX IN controller as follows:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<XVesselMaster> allVessel = new List<COMIS_tbl_VesselMaster>();
    List<XVessel_Transaction_Header> allVoyage = new List<XVessel_Transaction_Header>();

    allVessel = db.XVesselMaster.OrderBy(x => x.Vessel_Name).ToList();
    allVoyage = db.XVessel_Transaction_Header.OrderBy(x => x.Voyage_ID).ToList();

    ViewBag.ddl1 = new SelectList(allVessel,  "Vessel_ID", "Vessel_Name");
    ViewBag.ddl2 = new SelectList(allVoyage, "Voyage_ID", "Voyage_ID");
    return View();//dropdownlist
}
```

when i run it it throws internal server error. Saw some ppl saying to change the GET to POST, then it says path not found.

the JSON function is as follows

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetVoyages(string vesselID = "")
{

    string avc = vesselID;
    List<COMIS_tbl_Vessel_Transaction_Header> allVoyage = new List<COMIS_tbl_Vessel_Transaction_Header>();
    int ID = 0;
    if (int.TryParse(vesselID, out ID))
    {
        allVoyage = db.COMIS_tbl_Vessel_Transaction_Header.Where(a => a.Vessel_ID.Equals(ID)).OrderBy(a => a.Voyage_ID).ToList();
    }

    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        return new JsonResult
        {
            Data = allVoyage,
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        };
    }
    else
    {

        return new JsonResult
        {
            Data = "Not valid request",
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        };
    }
}
```

and INDEX VIEW as follows:

```
@model X.ViewModels2.VoyageData 
@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "Voyage Information"; 
} 

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{

    <div id="vesselNo">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m =>m.Vessel_ID,@ViewBag.ddl1 as SelectList , "-- Select Vessel--")
    </div>

    <br />
    <br />

    <div id="voyageNo">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m =>m.Voyage_ID,@ViewBag.ddl2 as SelectList , "-- Select Voyage--")
    </div>

    <br />
    <br />

    <div id="VMResults">
    </div>

}
```

not sure how to fix it. Would appreciate the help.

Comment: **Internal Server Error** means an error occurred (possibly) in your `GetVoyages` function. You need to step through this with your debugger to see the exact error. To help with debugging you can also enable IIS with _web.config_ to report the errors to the browser (for security reasons by default this is not enabled).

Comment: i did step through and it pulled the values i needed from the first dropdown but somehow it not sending it to the second dropdown.